# Adobe Flex HTTPService AsyncResponder onResult handler fires twice?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, handler, httpservice

My HTTPService resultHandler is firing twice.  Is that normal? The messageId and token# are the same. StatusCode=200 both times.

I've examined the traffic in Fiddler and only one request is being submitted. Here's a code snippet; I've put a breakpoint on the service send() method and it is happening only once.

```
    var token: AsyncToken;
    var myResponder : AsyncResponder = new AsyncResponder(onResult, onFault);
    token=myHTTPService.send();   
    token.addResponder(myResponder);

    private  function  onResult(e:ResultEvent , token:Object=null):void {
        **// we enter this function twice**
    }
```

Comment: What major / minor / patch version of the Flex SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a bug.
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-22883

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this problem as well! I guess the solution is to move on to Flex3.5.. thats what the bug tracking page says when I saw it today 17/feb/2010

Comment: Just wire-up a dummy eventhandler for the result and fault, and you can continue to use the AsyncResponder.

// these handler stubs are necessary because of http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-22883

this.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,onFaultEventHandler);
this.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,onResultEventHandler);
  
protected function onFaultEventHandler(e:FaultEvent): void{};
protected function onResultEventHandler(e:ResultEvent):void {};